# UseDApp TransactionStatus not working in Brave

Tags: state, brave-browser

I used `useEffect` with status of the transaction in dependency array:

```js
const { send: approveErc20Send, state: approveErc20State } =
        useContractFunction(tokenContract, "approve", {
            transactionName: "Approve ERC20 transfer"
        })
```

After i call the approveErc20Send function I `console.log` it's state status:

```js
const deposit = (amount, timeLocked) => {
        setAmountToDeposit(amount);
        setTimeToLock(timeLocked);
        return approveErc20Send(protocolAddress, amount)
    }


useEffect(() => {
        console.log(approveErc20State.status)
    }, [approveErc20State])
```

Same code is working in Chrome but not in Brave(in dev enviorment). Any ideas why that is?

using **useDApp** and **Next.js**

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I just had to restart the browner. No idea what really happened.